# LOWER and REPLACE doesn't work on dynamic linq where statement

Tags: c#, replace, sql-server-2008-r2, lowercase, dynamic-linq

Here is my code ,

```
db.myDBContext.my_tables.Where("REPLACE(LOWER(name),\" \",\"\") == \"{0}\"", value);
```

it show the error

```
No applicable method 'LOWER' exists in type 'my_table'
```

can't I use `REPLACE` and `LOWER` in dynamic linq clause ?

Comment: Is this for SQL Server?

Comment: yes @juharr , for SQL Server !

Comment: Is `name` supposed to be a variable representing a column name, or is it literally a column named "name"?

Comment: `name` is a column name @Crowcoder , not a variable !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic Linq doesn't understand T-SQL. You will want to craft it this way:

```
.Where(string.Format("(name).ToLower().Replace(\" \", \"\") == \"{0}\" ", value))
```

There is an analog for `ToLower` and `Replace` in T-SQL and Linq knows how to translate them from c#.
But if `name` is a static column name then @Jonny is on to something. You don't need Dynamic Linq here (unless this is just a contrived example of a bigger problem you are solving).

Answer (score 0):

How about building it this way?

```
Where(t=>t.name.toLower() == value)
```